# Python: check if string is in any items in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a `server_list` and I am parsing email addresses from a file. I want to collect all addresses that are not from certain servers e.g. gmail.com.

Currently I have this inside the file reading loop:

```
server_list = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"] #etc
for servers in server_list:
   if servers in emailaddress: #get emailaddress from inside of a open(file) line loop
        badmail.extend(emailaddress)
```

This allows me to collect the bad emails in a list `badmail`. Is there any way to create a list of  good emails i.e. if `emailaddress` is not contained in any items in `server_list` in the same loop or do I have to create a list of all emails and remove the bad emails?

Comment: Sounds like you could just handle that in the `else`

Comment: what is `emailaddress`? A list?

Comment: You could simplify to `if any(servers in emailaddress for servers in server_list):`. Also, you probably want to `append`, not `extend`, the list, assuming it's a string.

Comment: emailaddress is a string extracted from a line in the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function to make sure that the emailaddress doesn't end with any of the servers in the `server_list`, like this

```
server_list, good_email = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"], []
if all(not emailaddress.endswith(server) for server in server_list):
    good_email.append(emailaddress)
```

The same way, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function to get the bad email address, like this

```
server_list, bad_email = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"], []
if any(emailaddress.endswith(server) for server in server_list):
    bad_email.append(emailaddress)
```

Looks like you are reading the email addresses from a file. So, you can do something like this

```
server_list, good_list, bad_list = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"], [], []
with open("email.txt") as in_file:
    for email_address in in_file:
        email_address = email_address.rstrip()
        if any(email_address.endswith(server) for server in server_list):
            bad_list.append(email_address)
        else:
            good_list.append(email_address)
```

As per [`lvc`'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338557/python-check-if-string-is-in-any-items-in-a-list/23338645?noredirect=1#comment35739171_23338645), we can actually pass a tuple of data to [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). So, the code can be further simplified to

```
server_list, good_list, bad_list = ("gmail.com", "yahoo.com"), [], []
...
...
if email_address.endswith(server_list):
    bad_list.append(email_address)
else:
    good_list.append(email_address)
```

Comment: +1, but you should just use `if/else` instead of checking the same thing twice.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks :) I was editing the answer, please check now.

Comment: You could use `email_address.endswith(tuple(server_list))` rather than a genexp, or even make `server_list` a tuple to start with.

Comment: thank you, this is very useful. However I notice you have made it to check only the ends - is there any way to check all parts too? i.e. like .contains?

Comment: @Kash That is simple :) You can do `any(server in email_address for server in server_list)`